# Perfect forwarding with type restrictions

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

I would like to use perfect forwarding on a templated function to ensure l-valuedness or r-valuedness is preserved, but at the same time I would like to impose certain restrictions on the possible parameter types.

Suppose for example I just want to restrict `T` to a callable object.
The following approach looks correct to me

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_callable<T>>::value>::type myFun(T&& val) 
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

but since I am still not yet fully comfortable with the various SFINAE nuances I would appreciate someone else's feedback.

Would this be the correct and idiomatic way to go about it?

Comment: Why not specialize the template for `Allowed_Type` and disable the general template?

Comment: Would that be a better solution?

Comment: (Almost) always prefer overloading when you want to handle a specific type.

Comment: @AndyG: Agreed, I'd just have two overloads here, `void myFun(const Allowed_Type&)` and `void myFun(Allowed_Type&&)` and no templates at all.

Comment: @AndyG If I wanted to check for `is_callable` instead, would you do it differently?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon: Yes, absolutely. But I think that you'll find some of your compiler errors disappear with that instead of `std::is_same` :-)

Comment: I am afraid I have chosen a bad example, please see edited question.

Comment: `&& T val` -> `T && val`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oops.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_callable` is a C++17 feature, by the way.

Anyhow, since your function `myFun` doesn't return anything, it's a little weird to put the `enable_if` as the return value. Yeah, it'll become `void` when the template is selected, but it's probably more legible to place it as a default template argument:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable_v<T()>, int> = 0>
void myFun(T&& val) 
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pMevtv48zwCKvCUs)

Although it would be a little bit strange for your `enable_if` to exist in a vacuum. At the very least, we should catch all the types that don't fit in and provide the user with a good compiler error via `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable_v<T()>, int> =0>
void myFun(T&& val) 
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(val));
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_callable_v<T()>, int> =0>
void myFun(T&& val) 
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "myFun is only callable with an argument that can be called as a function with no params");
}
```

[Demo2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CKTWCKKz5su6tMPN)

Comment: Except for the issue that MSVC is broken and doesn't understand it, `std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable<T()>{},int> = 0` has better overload resolution properties than `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable<T()>{}>` does.

Comment: @Yakk: Updated, thanks. Is there a preference between `std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable<T()>{},int> = 0` and `template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_callable<T()>::value, int> = 0>` besides the fact that in the former there will be an implicit conversion to bool and no need to check `::value`?

Comment: `::value` is 5 more characters than `{}`.  Alternatively, `std::is_callable_v<T()>` given that this is a C++17 trait is also as short.

Comment: Why use enable_if at all then ? Just the static_assert would be enough to fail if the type does not match the conditions.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: Removing the enable_if on the second definition makes a function call ambiguous for types that satisfy `std::is_callable`

Comment: I am saying : juste one templated function with a static_assert(is_callable) in it. No need of enable_if at all. No need of an overload to get an error with types not matching the condition. SFINAE, at it clearly states, is for not having errors.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: That's quite reasonable in this situation.